# Find closest similar siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click on the `<i>`, the `<a>`, or the `<li>` and get all the `<li>`s.

The point is to detect the closest repetitive element no matter how deep in it's children you click.

This is what I have so far: It shows the count of the siblings but what I'd like to isolate is same-ness.

For example: `<body>` shows 2 siblings but they are not both `<body>`. `<header>` shows 4 but they not all `<header>`. How do I only count same siblings. In this case `<li>` but can be anything.

//Run in full-page↗️

```js
$('body').on('click', (e) => {
  $el = $(e.target);

  $parentsAndSelf = $el.parents().addBack();
  
  $parentsAndSelf.each( (i,el) => {
    if( $(el).siblings().addBack().length > 1){
      console.log( el,  $(el).siblings().addBack().length );
      //return false;
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px;
  margin:5px;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

a {
  display: block
}

.highlight{
  background:yellow;
}

*:hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  HEADER:
  <nav>
    NAV:
    <ul>
      UL:
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>1</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>2</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>3</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>4</i></a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start with a pretty simple JavaScript idea before presenting the jQuery one:

### JavaScript - Get first closest multiple siblings

This could be easily made by using [Element.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with a `":scope >"` query for immediate child elements of the same `Element.tagName`, and a **recursive function**:

```js
const closestMultiple = el => {
  const par = el.parentElement;
  const sib = par && par.querySelectorAll(`:scope > ${el.tagName}`);
  return (sib && sib.length > 1 ? sib : par && closestMultiple(par))
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const cm = closestMultiple(ev.target)
  if(cm) cm.forEach(EL => EL.classList.toggle("highlight"));
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  list-style-position: inside;
  background: #fff;
}
*:hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  display: block
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    HEADER:
  </div>
  <div>
    <nav>
      NAV:
      <ul>
        UL:
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>1</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>2</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>3</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>4</i></a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

### jQuery - Get first closest multiple siblings

- Invert the array using `.reverse()` to speed up the process starting from the *Target Element* (instead of *document*).
- Stop the loop as soon as [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) matches the `length > 1` criteria:

```js
function closestMultiple(el, $mu) {
  return $(el).parents().addBack().get().reverse().some(el => {
    const $gr = $(el).siblings(el.tagName).addBack();
    return ($gr.length > 1 ? $mu = $gr : 0);
  }) && $mu || $();
}
```

```js
function closestMultiple(el, $mu) {
  return $(el).parents().addBack().get().reverse().some(el => {
    const $gr = $(el).siblings(el.tagName).addBack();
    return ($gr.length > 1 ? $mu = $gr : 0);
  }) && $mu || $();
}

$(document).on('click', (ev) => {
  const $clRep = closestMultiple(ev.target).toggleClass("highlight");
  console.clear(); console.log($clRep.length +" "+ $clRep.prop("tagName"));
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  list-style-position: inside;
  background: #fff;
}
*:hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  display: block
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    HEADER:
  </div>
  <div>
    <nav>
      NAV:
      <ul>
        UL:
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>1</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>2</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>3</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>4</i></a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### jQuery micro-plugin

For a nicer experience (since you're already using jQuery) you could extend the `jQuery` constructor with your own `.closestMultiple()` method.
Here's a suggestion for a Micro-plugin:

```js
$.fn.closestMultiple = function($mu) {
  return this.parents().addBack().get().reverse().some(el => {
    const $gr = $(el).siblings(el.tagName).addBack();
    return ($gr.length > 1 ? $mu = $gr : 0);
  }) && $mu || $();
}

$(document).on('click', (ev) => {
  $(ev.target).closestMultiple().toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  list-style-position: inside;
  background: #fff;
}

a {
  display: block
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}

*:hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    HEADER:
  </div>
  <div>
    <nav>
      NAV:
      <ul>
        UL:
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>1</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>2</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>3</i></a> </li>
        <li>li <a href="#">item <i>4</i></a> </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This really got me occupied hehe.

So if:

> The point is to detect the closest repetitive element no matter how
> deep in it's children you click.

It means:

- you have to get parent of clicked element
- search for its children, if any, get its tag-names (types), react if two are the same
- if not, move to next parent, do the same

> I want to be able to click on the `<i>`, the `<a>`, or the `<li>` and
> get all the `<li>`s.

Example:

```js
let num
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  num = 1;
  let el = event.target
  let s
  check(s, el)
})

function check(s, el) {
  console.clear()

  // jumping parents part and getting only first level children
  let ss = ".parentNode"
  s = "el" + ss.repeat(num) + ".children"

  // map tagnames
  let c = [...eval(s)].map(type => type.tagName)

  // isolate duplicates part
  const yourArray = c
  const yourArrayWithoutDuplicates = [...new Set(yourArray)]
  let duplicates = [...yourArray]
  yourArrayWithoutDuplicates.forEach((item) => {
    const i = duplicates.indexOf(item)
    duplicates = duplicates
      .slice(0, i)
      .concat(duplicates.slice(i + 1, duplicates.length))
  })

  // if no duplicates call this same function just add num++ to add .parentNode
  // it will loop unitl it hits 2 same tagnames on same level, sibilings
  duplicates.length === 0 ? (num++, check(eval(s), el)) : (console.log("Repeting element :" + duplicates[0]), console.log("Repets: " + (parseInt(duplicates.length) + 1)), console.log("Position from clicked element: " + s))

}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

a {
  display: block
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}

*:hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  HEADER:
  <nav>
    NAV:
    <ul>
      UL:
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>1</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>2</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>3</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>4</i></a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**EDIT:**

And here is a bit more simplified version still following same logic:

```js
let num
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  num = 1;
  let s
  check(s, event.target)
})

function check(s, el) {
  console.clear()
  const ss = ".parentNode"
  s = "el" + ss.repeat(num) + ".children";
  let count = {};
  [...eval(s)].map(type => type.tagName).forEach( i => {count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1})
  const max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.values(count));

  max <= 1 ? (num++, check(eval(s), el)) : (console.log("Repeting element :" + Object.keys(count)[0]), console.log("Repets: " + max), console.log("Position from clicked element: " + s))
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

a {
  display: block
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}

*:hover {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  HEADER:
  <nav>
    NAV:
    <ul>
      UL:
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>1</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>2</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>3</i></a> </li>
      <li>li <a href="#">item <i>4</i></a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating the task with evaling, indexing, Set-ing, mapping, slicing, concatenating and than making a recursion and all over again. PS: `eval` is *evil* only if you pass arbitrary strings into it (It's considered bad practice because if novice programmers start to use it - they use it everywhere without understanding the serious implications) therefore I see no place to provide `eval` right into a code that someone will most likely *just* copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks for your time trying on this. I like the break down of logic.

Comment: @Miro Np, it was a good question, had fun with it.

Answer (score -2):

I think this simple way may help you:

```
  $("i, a, li").on('click', function(event) {
      var closest_li = $(this).closest('ul').find('li');

      console.log(closest_li);
  });
```

So you will get array of all `<li>` elements which exist in parent `<ul>`.

Comment: I believe point of question is, not knowing on witch element in document you are going to click and nether witch elements are repeating, it does not have to be li, so your targeting directly of both of those has no use. Just to explain my down vote.

Comment: @ikiK This is just an example of how to get closest elements. I found it helpful for asked question. Is this wrong? If it isn't, for why vote down?

Comment: I explained why is wrong, and it is not helpful to OP's question.